# Lotus Notes Locks on "CC" to a Specific User

Tags: email

One of our users has an interesting issue.  If he sends an email to a specific user, everything goes normally.  However, if he "cc's" that user in an email, his Lotus Notes locks up.  Where do I look for a solution???